# MergeSort right part of array

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm new in java and I have task to do - mergeSort but I have one question from my teacher according to the right side of the array but I have no idea how to do it. Here is my code:

```
public class MergeSort {
    private int[] array;
    private int[] tempArray;

    public int[] sort(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
        this.tempArray = new int[array.length];
        mergeSort(0, array.length - 1);
        return array;
    }

    private void mergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
        if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
            int middleIndex = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;
            mergeSort(lowerIndex, middleIndex);
            mergeSort(middleIndex + 1, higherIndex);
            merge(lowerIndex, middleIndex, higherIndex);
        }
    }

    private void merge(int lowerIndex, int middleIndex, int higherIndex) {
        for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++) {
            tempArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = middleIndex + 1;
        int k = lowerIndex;
        while (i <= middleIndex && j <= higherIndex) {
            if (tempArray[i] <= tempArray[j]) {
                array[k] = tempArray[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                array[k] = tempArray[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while (i <= middleIndex) {
            array[k] = tempArray[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly but, as I mentioned earlier, my teacher asked me: "You are handling half of the merge - please note that you have also second array (right one) and there may be elements when the one on left is empty".

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anything wrong with logic. May be your teacher ask you to add this in your `merge` function,

```
while (j <= higherIndex) {
        array[k] = tempArray[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
```

You code work perfectly with or without this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it was exactly what he is looking for.